# Google Cloud Storage credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I have issue with Ruby (Gcloud gem) and Google Cloud storage.
I need safe all my documents (files) on google storage via API.
I have json file and follow google tutorial.

```
require "gcloud"
storage = Gcloud.storage "my-app-name",
                         "#{Rails.root}/config/8796474039a3.json"
```

After that I try to get all buckets

```
storage.bucket
```

And got error

```
Caught error forbidden: Forbidden
Error - #<Google::Apis::ClientError: forbidden: Forbidden>
```

Could any help me with that?
Maybe I need to pass something else?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this app locally, on app engine. or on GCE?